# Make multiple columns into one column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, multiple-columns

I have a table `Employee` which have several fields like `FirstName,LastName,Email,.......` . So what i want to do is that in my case selection of column is dynamic

```
Declare @columnNeeded nvarchar(max)
```

**Example one**

```
Set @columnNeeded = 'FirstName,Email'
Select @columnNeeded from Employee
```

**Example Two**

```
Set @columnNeeded = 'FirstName,LastName'
Select @columnNeeded from Employee
```

This is pretty simple , now what i want is that regardless of what column will be in result set i need all column selected in one column as comma seperated string . I saw Group_Concat() in mysql but don't know how to do this in sql .So is this possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select @columns from Employee';
declare @columnNeeded nvarchar(max) = 'FirstName,Email';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@columns', @columnNeeded);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

EDIT:

If you want them as one column, you could do:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select @columns from Employee';
declare @columnNeeded nvarchar(max) = 'FirstName,Email';

set @sql = replace(replace(@sql, '@columns', @columnNeeded), ',', '+'',''+');

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

To type-safe you would cast the column values:

```
declare @tmp nvarchar(4000) = 'cast(' +
                              replace(@columnNeeded, ',', ', nvarchar(4000)), cast(') +
                              ', nvarchar(4000))'
set @sql = replace(replace(@sql, '@columns', @columnNeeded), ',', '+'',''+');
```

If this works as expected, it adds `cast(<col> as nvarchar(4000))` to each of the columns in the list.

Comment: Its not selecting multiple column i questioned that how to get them into one column as comma seperated string

Comment: Yes , now they are in one column but still they are not comma seperated can you edit your answer ?

Comment: Its not working `Type casting error` , may be because every field would have different dataType . What we will do in this situation ?

Comment: Can we do this type safe anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Dynamic SQL`. Since you have different `Data types` in your table you may have to `convert` the `columns` to `Varchar` to `concatenate` the result into single column.

```
DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(max),
        @cols NVARCHAR(max) ='FirstName,Email'

SELECT @cols = 'convert(varchar(100),'
           + Replace(@cols+')+', ',', ')+'',''+convert(varchar(100),')

SELECT @cols = LEFT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)

SET @sql ='select ' + @cols + ' from Employee '

--print @sql
EXEC Sp_executesql @sql;
```

**Working Example :**

```
CREATE TABLE #test1([Key] INT,ID    INT,Value VARCHAR(2))

INSERT #test1
VALUES (1,1,'C' ),(2,1,'C' ),(3,1,'I' )

DECLARE @sql  NVARCHAR(max),
        @cols NVARCHAR(max) ='ID,Value'

SELECT @cols = 'convert(varchar(100),'
           + Replace(@cols+')+', ',', ')+'',''+convert(varchar(100),')

SELECT @cols = LEFT(@cols, Len(@cols) - 1)

SET @sql ='select ' + @cols + ' from #test1 '

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Any chance of a small, working example, even just using a table variable and maybe 3 columns of different types. Otherwise looks good.

Comment: @srutzky - Updated my answer with an example

Comment: Thanks. I just tested it with also adding a DATETIME field, just to see how that played out. It converts as the `Jan 1 2014 12:00AM` format. Of course, selectively adding a style number to appropriate fields is a whole other level of fun ;-). Either way, +1.